# Email Validation Javascript allowing *@domain.com

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate email addresses, it's easy, there are lots of RegEx while I search Google, but here, I want to also allow `*@domain.com`, here is what I have right now:

```
/^[\w-\.\d*]+@[\w\d]+(\.\w{2,4})$/
```

This works just fine for regular email addresses like `test@yahoo.com` and it also does what I want: `*@somedomain.com`, but this doesn't allow `test@yahoo.co.uk`.

How I should fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: «I want to validate email addresses, it's easy» - Yeah, sure xD

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario :)) I meant the regular ones not allowing *@etc.vom :-D

Comment: Please.. don't use some lame regex to validate email addresses. It is extremely annoying if e.g. `+` is not accepted in the localpart.

Comment: @ThiefMaster do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `+` after `(\.\w{2,4})` match:

```
/^[\w-\.\d*]+@[\w\d]+(\.\w{2,4})+$/
```